# jQueryUI sortable flickering and jumping when trying to order and place items in the list

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using jQueryUI sortable, when I have a long list of items, and I try to change the order and drag them around the items flicker and jump around the screen making it virtually impossible to order any of the items.

It looks like when you drag the item the "place here" place holder is miles away from where you actually want to drop the item?

How can I eliminate the flickering and jumping around the screen when trying to move / order items?

I have a full demo here 
http://jsfiddle.net/w3vvL/63/

I am now running out of ideas here. So any help would be great!

The code below is just a snippet, the rest is in the fiddle above. Thanks

```
    //Connect the two lists enable dragging between each one
    $("#gallery").sortable({
        revert: true,
        connectWith: "#trash",
        refreshPositions: true,

        // Newly added to change container background
        start: function(event, ui) {
            $("li.ui-state-highlight").text("place here"); 
            $(".containerTwo").stop().animate({"background-color":"#ffb9b9", "border-color":"#f06666", "border-top-style":"dashed", "border-right-style":"dashed", "border-bottom-style":"dashed", "border-left-style":"dashed",  "border-width":"1px"}, 500);
        }, 
        stop: function(event, ui) {
             $(".containerTwo").stop().animate({"background-color":"#fff", "border-color":"#aaa", "border-top-style":"solid", "border-right-style":"solid", "border-bottom-style":"solid", "border-left-style":"solid",  "border-width":"1px"}, 50);
        }
    });

    $("#trash").sortable({
        revert: true,
        connectWith: "#gallery",
        refreshPositions: true,

        // Newly added to change container background
        start: function(event, ui) {
            $("li.ui-state-highlight").text("place here"); 
            $(".container").stop().animate({"background-color":"#d4f7cd", "border-color":"#51965a", "border-top-style":"dashed", "border-right-style":"dashed", "border-bottom-style":"dashed", "border-left-style":"dashed",  "border-width":"1px"}, 500);
        }, 
        stop: function(event, ui) {
              $(".container").stop().animate({"background-color":"#fff", "border-color":"#aaa", "border-top-style":"solid", "border-right-style":"solid", "border-bottom-style":"solid", "border-left-style":"solid",  "border-width":"1px"}, 50);
        }
```

Comment: Try to add `float: left;` to `#gallery li`

Comment: I can't add something valuable but please don't call my method `swapIcons`. This is totally misleading because the method isn't swapping any icons. What it actually does is, it changes the place of a list element in the DOM. The list element then has a stylesheet which shows a different icon in each of the containers it can be dropped. This happens implicit and has nothing to do with what the function actually does.

Comment: float left does the job, however when i do the same for #trash li {float:left} when i try to drag from one div to the other and vise versa the "place here" doesnt display unless you drag right to the top of the div? any ideas how to solve that? cheers for the reply!

Comment: This happens because of the `ul` having a height of 0 when `float: left` is enabled on all of its child elements. Adding `overflow: hidden` to the `ul` will fix this but will reintroduce the flickering.

Comment: Solution is to add clearfix on `ul` ( I.E. with `:after` and `:before`), but current code is a bit messed up with inline css, and I don't have time to fix that right now :/

Comment: cheers guys, yeah it does solve it but like you say the flickering is there again. Any way to get both working without the flickering? Dont suppose you get add bit more info "add clearfix on ul ( I.E. with :after and :before)" not sure what you mean. Thanks both again

Comment: tried clearfix class on the ul but the flickering was still there, clearfix from http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

Comment: think the clearfix worked however now when i "remove all" the items and try and add or drag one back into the selected area - it simply WONT go in there!!

Comment: I cant seem to figure this out at all, been at it all day. Cant get both working together no matter what i try. Dont suppose you could help us out? Cheers. Driving me nutts

Comment: I am having the same problem with items as well (Flickering and jumping) Did you manage to fix your problem? If so, can you please post a code snippet?

Comment: Do you have a solution ? @Krishna

Answer (score 1):

By adding float left it will stop the flicking.

```
.dvdlist li {
display:inline-block;
border:1px solid #000;
cursor:move;
color: #222;
margin: 3px 3px 3px 0;
padding: 5px;
width: auto;
height: auto;
font-size: 12px;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid #aaa;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #FDFCE8; 
float:left;
}
```